# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CONCAT( REPEAT

Tags: magento-1.9, error, sql

When i go to Magento Admin and then SM Menu Item Manager:

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CONCAT( REPEAT( "---   ", (COUNT(parent.depth) - 1) ) , main_table.title)' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `mgroup`.`title` AS `group_name`, `CONCAT( REPEAT( "---   ", (COUNT(parent.depth) - 1) ) , main_table`.`title)` AS `name` FROM `sm_menu_items` AS `main_table`
>    INNER JOIN `sm_menu_groups` AS `mgroup` ON mgroup.id = main_table.group_id
>    CROSS JOIN `sm_menu_items` AS `parent` WHERE (main_table.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt) AND (parent.group_id = main_table.group_id) GROUP BY `main_table`.`id` ORDER BY `main_table`.`group_id` ASC, `main_table`.`lft` ASC, id ASC LIMIT 20

```
#0 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/local/Sm/Megamenu/Block/Adminhtml/Menuitems/Grid.php(39): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#11 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Sm_Megamenu_Block_Adminhtml_Menuitems_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#12 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#13 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#14 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#16 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#17 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#18 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/smartphon...')
#19 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#20 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#24 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#26 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#28 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#29 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/smartphon...')
#30 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#31 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#32 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#33 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#34 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#35 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#36 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/local/Sm/Megamenu/controllers/Adminhtml/MenuitemsController.php(23): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#37 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Sm_Megamenu_Adminhtml_MenuitemsController->indexAction()
#38 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#39 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#40 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#41 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#42 /home/demo/domains/demo-accessoires.com/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#43 {main}
```

Comment: You may try Following url http://www.magentech.com/documentation/how-to-fix-sm-megamenu-error-when-update-to-magento-v1-9-2-0/

Answer (score 1):

It seems the installation went wrong or you accidentally remove the field from the database. Try adding the field, it is a varchar 255.

Comment: which table field  varchar 255?